# Reverse Engineering an ERP interface written in Flash

Tags: flash, websites

My college has its ERP platform in a Flash interface, accessible only via Internet Explorer. I am looking into ways I can interface with it via things like [ruffle](https://ruffle.rs/). So I can write my own frontend using modern frameworks. Thing is, accessing the ERP from anything other Internet Explorer results in the browser download a Flash file `campus-lynx.swf`. This means the platform is locked to Windows only. Flashfox on Android works as well.

The ERP is available directly at erp.nitdelhi.ac.in or clicking "internet" at the top of nitdelhi.ac.in.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: What should my approach be? Extracting the downloaded swf file lead me to nowhere.

Comment: What’s “erp”? Maybe add an explanation what exactly it does.

Comment: Ah its a portal for resource management where teachers can update grades and attendance, and students can see the above along with register for sems

Answer (score 3):

Intercept the traffic between the browser / plugins and the server. I would start with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

The traffic between the client and the server will be some form of network requests which you can write code to generate / consume.

Answer (score 3):

> My college has its erp platform in a flash interface, accesible only via Internet Explorer.
> Thing is, accessing the erp from amything other internet explorer results in the browser download a flash file "campus-lynx.swf". This means the platform is locked to windows only.

You are obviously wrong. Application work in firefox without any problems. Even site itself state "Best Peformed With Mozilla FireFox Version 2 and above".

Most recent Firefox versions start dropping Flash support, that may be the case. But you always can install portable version of Firefox 52 without this issue.

Judging by controls look and feel the application was build with Adobe Flex Builder.

There was several commercial Flash decompilers such as https://www.eltima.com/products/flashdecompiler/
You can try to decompile SWF file to figure out protocols being used.

Most probably there is something standard such as XML or [Action Message Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format).

UPD: Network activity tab in browser clearly indicate usage of AMF protocol. There is a plenty of AMF support libraries for various programming languages. Google it.